# Amazon AWS: Failing to Login

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webexception

I've been working on an amazon EC2 project and when I login like this:

```
public bool Login(Credentials credentials, string ownerID, string region)
{
    try
    {
        OwnerID = ownerID;
        CurrentCredentials = credentials;
        CurrentConfigs = new AmazonEC2Config() { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region) };
        EC2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(CurrentCredentials, CurrentConfigs);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then try to access like this:

```
DescribeInstancesRequest ec2Request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
ec2Request.InstanceIds = new List<string>() { id };
DescribeInstancesResponse ec2Response = EC2.DescribeInstances(ec2Request);
return ec2Response.Reservations[0].Instances[0];
```

I get this exception:

**EXCEPTION:**

```
Encountered a WebException (NameResolutionFailure), the request cannot be retried. Either the maximum number of retries has been exceeded (4/4) or the request is using a non-seekable stream.
```

**STACK TRACE:**

```
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.HandleHttpWebErrorResponse(AsyncResult asyncResult, WebException we)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)
at Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Client.DescribeInstances(DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstancesRequest)
at ...
```

**EDIT:**

This exception's inner exception is:

```
The remote name could not be resolved: 'ec2.sa-east-1a.amazonaws.com'
```

*It's important to point out that it only gives me this error when the access is to region **sa-east-1a**. Another account I have in region **us-west-2** works perfectly. Also, I have extracted the Credential and Region information from the web.config*

Comment: Similar: I saw this same error message recently and it turns out our web proxy is http, not https... I successfully connected by setting `AmazonS3Config.UseHttp = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple error, simple solution: The region is **sa-east-1** not **sa-east-1a**. When logging in, you shouldn't specify which datacenter to use, just the region.

Answer (score 1):

As an appendix to this, to anyone arriving here who wasn't specifying the datacenter. In my case using `RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("USEast1")` vs `RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("US-East-1")` was the difference maker.